# Twitterizer.net - update post Unauthorized, Timestamp out of bounds

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitterizer

I am using Twitterizer .net in order to make a console app in c# and post some twit updates from my twit app.

I created the app in twitter and have all the right tokens set

In my program I send twitter status like this

```
public static bool Twit(string message)
{
     var options = new StatusUpdateOptions();
     TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(OathTokenHelper.OathTokens, message, options);
     return tweetResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success;
}
```

And as a result I get a "Timestamp out of bounds" and status "Unauthorized"

I have checked my Computer time and all is fine. Do you know what it might be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your local PC time is not GMT?

Comment: GMT+2, but I suppose the system knows the GMT time

Answer (score 0):

Reg : status "Unauthorized"

Make sure that your application has below access level

**Access level   Read, write, and direct messages**

Answer (score 0):

More details : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/299

Have a look at this extract from the above page

"If your access token is read-only then it's likely you negotiated it when your app was set to a read-only state. To re-negotiate it, the best way is to first go to https://twitter.com/settings/applications and find the application then revoke it's access. Wait about 5 minutes to make sure that our system caches have cleared and then obtain your access token again either through OAuth or the "my access token" feature on this site after making sure that the application settings/permission type are as you wish them to be."